# Sending data to server in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am sending data to to server with AJAX using

```
function post(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', url);
    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };
    var data = moldData();
    alert(JSON.stringify(data , null , 2 ))
    req.send( data );
  });
}

send.addEventListener('click', function(){
    post('http://localhost:8080/order').then(function(){
        alert('send')
    }).catch(function(e){
        alert(e)
    })
}
```

on server side i am using

```
app.post('/order', function( req , res ){
  console.log('sup')
  console.log("=================\n" , req.body)
})
```

But whenever i post it , the promise does not get resolved nor rejected e.g
then nor catch gets executed. And on server side it just prints

"==============="
"[Object object]"

I am using body parser e.g

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.raw())
app.use(bodyParser.text())
```

I am fairly new to the backend development, why is this happening? What causes this? using

```
console.log(JSON.stingify(req.body,null,2))
```

results in the same output.

Thanks for help!

// 
Although the one part of question got answered. The main question was why req.body isnt printed , but instead , [Object object] is printed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your server side code logs two things and then stops.

The browser waits for a while and should *eventually* time out and reject the promise.

You have to send a response!

Look at the [hello world example](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html):

> ```
> res.send('Hello World!');
> ```

Comment: Oh , but why does it does not log data as it should? Instead it logs just [Object object]?

Comment: @Frer because that's what you get when you force an object to be a string without JSON.stringify

Answer (score -1):

You need to stringify the server response when logging it.

```
console.log("=================\n" , JSON.stringify(req.body))
```

If you want to "pretty-print" the output, you can do this:

```
console.log("=================\n" , JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4))
```

Comment: Downvoter, why was this downvoted? At the end of his question he summarised with "why is `[Object object]` printed?`.